# iOS download mp3 to app's sandbox

Tags: ios, mp3

i want to play mp3 on my iphone app. I can streaming the mp3 from my server now (by using MPMoviePlayerViewController). However, i want to add the function that enable the user to download the mp3, then play it locally when there's no internet connection.

There's an app called **Elevation** does exactly the same thing. It will download the mp3 into the app's sandbox (not the ipod library). And the users can delete it later if they want. Anyone know how it does that magic?

[image]

Comment: Just use a NSURLConnection and write it to the documents directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `NSURLConnection` **BUT** download the files **asynchronously** because synchronously connections will make your UI to be frozen while downloading files. Here's a clear example of how you do it, you only need to do small changes:

http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-uiimage-asynchronously/

Hope it helps.